# How to fix jquery filtering in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, html-select

I am facing a *jQuery* filtering problem in Google Chrome. I use MixItUp jQuery filter and sorting pluging for my web site. It's working great in Firefox but it does not work in Chrome. If I use this for filtering option it works in all browsers.

```
<a class="filter" data-filter="all">All</a>
<a class="filter" data-filter=".category-1">Category 1</a>
<a class="filter" data-filter=".category-2">Category 2</a>
```

but i want to use select option for this. It works in FF but not in Chrome.

```
<select class="form-control input-lg filter_s">
   <option value="All" class="filter" data-filter="all">Show All</option>
   <option value="email" class="filter" data-filter=".category-1">E-Mail</option>
   <option value="twitter" class="filter" data-filter=".category-2">Twitter</option>
   <option value="linkedin" class="filter" data-filter=".category-3">LinkedIn</option>
</select>
```

Here is the link of site

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88666744/HTML/works/qclor_problem/our_work.html

Comment: Why do your filter names start with a period? That seems odd.

Comment: didnot understand. which period you are talking about?

Comment: The category names start with a `.`

Comment: yes that's the instruction to use.https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/ see it here

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't fire onclick events for <option> elements. Chrome fires two onclick events for the parent <select>: one to show the list of options, the second one after an option is selected.

The plugin would have to handle select/option elements specially and bind to the onchange event (of the select) instead. Can you file a bug report?

**EDIT:**

If you want to *hack* (temporarily) the MixtItUp plugin to make it work for <select>s, grab the un-minimized, "jquery.mixitup.js" file and make the following changes:

**(1)** Find the following code:

```
            self._$filterButtons.on('click.mixItUp.'+self._id, function(){
                self._processClick($(this), 'filter');
            });
```

and replace it with:

```
            self._$filterButtons.each(function(i) {
                var e = $(this);
                switch(e.prop('tagName').toLowerCase()) {
                    case 'option':
                        var p = e.parent();
                        if (!p.hasClass('mixItUp-bound')) {
                            p.on('change.mixItUp.'+self._id, function(){
                                self._processClick(p, 'filter');
                            });
                            p.addClass('mixItUp-bound');
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        e.on('click.mixItUp.'+self._id, function(){
                            self._processClick(e, 'filter');
                        });
                }
            });
```

**(2)** Then, within the function

```
        _processClick: function($button, type){
```

where you'll find the two lines

```
            if(type === 'filter') {
                var filter = $button.attr('data-filter'),
```

insert a line such that you get in the end:

```
            if(type === 'filter') {
                $button = ($button.prop('tagName').toLowerCase() == 'select') ? $button.find(":selected") : $button;
                var filter = $button.attr('data-filter'),
```

---

Then again, this is a really a **hack** so you'll notice that if you use

```
{controls.live: true}
```

in the options it'll break again, and of course no change was made to the sorting part of the plugin.